# Use slicing to make a new string in the format lastname, firstname

Tags: python

There were other portions to this which I already completed, I just need assistance with getting the new_string2 to format as Last Name, First Name when the user inputs a full name. No syntax, it is only displaying just First Name Last Name. Thank you!

```
def main():
    full_name = input('Enter your full name: ')
    x = len(full_name) - 1
    print("Your name backwards is: ")
    while(x >= 0):
        print(full_name[x], end="")
        x -= 1


    y = full_name.index("")
    new_string2 = full_name[x+1:] + "" + full_name[0:y]
    print("\n""Alphabetically, your name is", new_string2 )


    new_string = full_name[x+1:] + "" + full_name[0:y]
    d={"UPPER_CASE":0, "LOWER_CASE":0}
    for c in full_name:
        if c.isupper():
            d["UPPER_CASE"]+=1
        elif c.islower():
           d["LOWER_CASE"]+=1
        else:
           pass
    print ("Your name has" , d["UPPER_CASE"] , "upper case letters and " , d["LOWER_CASE"] , "lower case letters")
    incorrect_string = "You have to be vewy, vewy twicky to twap a wascally wabbit"
    correct_string = incorrect_string.replace('w', 'r')
    print (correct_string)
main()
```

Comment: Is the first name and last name going to be separated by a space? Give example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just assumed that the last name will be always after the last space. And didn't care about the syntax just fixed your code.

Replace this

```
y = full_name.index("")
new_string2 = full_name[x+1:] + "" + full_name[0:y]
print("\n""Alphabetically, your name is", new_string2 )
```

For this:

```
y = full_name.split(" ")
new_string2 = y[-1:][0] + ", " + " ".join(y[:-1])
print("\n""Alphabetically, your name is", new_string2)
```

And remove the following line that is broken after the change:

```
new_string = full_name[x+1:] + "" + full_name[0:y]
```

If you prefer to use the first name as the word before the FIRST space use this code:

```
new_string2 = " ".join(y[1:]) + ", " + y[0]
```

Just be careful if the user input a name without any space, it is gonna break (index exception).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!